# What is the best way to implement templates in a programming language?

Tags: templates, language-design

I'm designing a high level, object oriented, garbage collected programming language, and I'm having a problem with how to do templates. I plan on creating a VM-type system, similar to .NET or JVM (but it will use LLVM under the hood). The problem is that I want to have powerful, C++-like templates, but with dynamic linking (so I could replace the template library without recompiling everything that uses it). I want to be able to compile a source file without having the definition of the templates. Code generation at JIT-time should be minimized.

Here are the options I'm thinking of:

- Have the concept of a template library which is statically linked into each compilation unit. A template library would essentially be like an AST with blanks to be filled in when the template is instantiated. The problem with this is that if two files are compiled with different versions of the template library, they may be incompatible, or if the template library is buggy, everything will have to be recompiled. This is how C++ does it.
- Have template libraries that are linked at JIT-time. This solves most of the problems but requires the IR to essentially be an AST. I would like the IR to be much lower level. This requires much more work for JIT-ing.
- Have wimpy C#-like generics with only types as arguments. This is quite limiting, but allows simple code generation and dynamic linking.

Are there any other good ways I'm not thinking of? I'm leaning towards the first option, but I don't really like any of the options. What do you think is the best option?

Answer (score 1):

I guess it depends on the amount of specialization you want, i.e. how powerful the compiler of templates has to be.

If you look at c++, the compiler can do all sorts of fancy stuff (like generate subclasses via recursion, probably compute a fractal inheritance graph as well as computing the numbers of Pi on the fly).

If you want that power, you probably need a powerful high-level JIT. FWIW, I think that would be cool. (Just include the full compiler in the runtime.)

Answer (score 0):

Depends a bit on the rest of the language... if you have operator overloading, value types etc, then you are really complicating matters (and possibly missing out on great optimisation opportunities) by not going the C++ route: the code using the template would also have to be represented as an AST up to JIT time to allow maximum specialization.

Since C++ templates are essentially a form of macros, they allow much of all the bloat produced by duplication to be reduced before you get generate code.

Template types (at least in C++) tend to be the most core types that underly all other code, as such, if they change, assuming other code will still be compatible with it is not going to be true for all but the smallest changes.

Answer (score 0):

What you're trying to achieve is nearly impossible. You have to leave pretty much all of the high level representation of your language for both the templates definitions and the code using those templates, and perform your JIT compilation from almost the level of slightly processed source code. If you're ok with that - you'd have to keep the rest of your compiler really trivial, and you won't be able to use any of the heavyweight LLVM optimisations. There are no other ways around, template metaprogramming relies on the availability of the high level information.

Answer (score 0):

Think about how powerful are these templates going to be. You must remember that having a language that is compiled Just In Time, means that a lot of the heavy lifting will have to be done at load time and at run time. So, the more powerful you make your templates the less performance you will get from them.

---

If you are really going to that path, you may also include the compiler in the run time as [Macke suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/a/809248/402022). In fact there are plenty of languages that do this.

By doing this you are making your implementation of the language an "interpreted" or partially "interpreted" one. In those terms a template is just a fancy dress for match-replace-eval, and there is anything wrong with that, templates often work like that in dynamic languages. Just remember that at the end it will be Power vs Performance.

---

Note: when facing this kind of decisions it may be worth to step back a little. Identify the use cases and prioritize them, separate how to implement from the design so you can iterate the design without having the implementation be a cause of paralysis, yet still having it into consideration.

Each iteration you extend the design to cover more use cases while deciding what will be the best design. When you reach a design you like you can iterate then you can iterate on the implementation too. This methodology allows you to cover the more important cases first.

Yes, I'm suggesting an iterative incremental methodology. And I do this because this question is about the design of a language yet it seems much concerned about the implementation. It is necessary to keep the ideas grounded or you will end up in one of the extremes (too much powerful with pity performance or no templates at all for a high performance solution).